# SonarQube 5.0 Upgrade - Large Instance Warning

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

We are considering to upgrade our SonarQube instances from 4.5.1 version to 5.1.1 version and per the [Release 5.1 Upgrade Notes](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Release+5.1+Upgrade+Notes), We noticed this warning:

Large Instance Warning
As with SonarQube 5.0, large instances (> 5M issues or > 25M lines) should not move to this version.

We have more than 50M lines of code, but the # of issues are much less than 5M issues.

What is the impact of this warning for our upgrade to 5.1.1.
Would this restrictions be removed in 5.2 version of SonarQube?

We are seeing huge performance issues during the Sonar Reports Analysis, which is performed by the Sonar Server in 5.1.1

Are these performance issues related to above warning?
Please advise how do we proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the warning is about the ability to support millions of issues and source lines in a reliable and performant way. This limitation will be fixed for next LTS version (probably 5.4). It is not known yet if it will be fixed earlier (5.2 or 5.3).